# <audio autoplay>をMobile Chrome Appsで使いたい

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-apps

[Mobile Chrome Apps](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps)でHTMLゲームを作っています。BGMの演奏に`<audio autoplay>`を使っていて、デスクトップChromeでのプレビューでは正しく動作しているのですが、`cca`コマンドでAndroidにデプロイすると音が出ません。
調べてみたところ[WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean))のようにすればネイティブのWebViewではなんとかなりそうな気がしたのですが、XWalkViewで同じようなことをする方法が見つからず困っています。

要はユーザーのジェスチャーと関係なくJavaScriptから音楽の演奏と停止をコントロールできれば良いのですが、良い方法はありますか？

Comment: 回答ではないのでコメントにさせてください。<audio>タグを使用して、assetフォルダなどローカルファイルの音楽ファイルを再生できない!みたいな同種のバグは[issue103](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/103)などで上がっているみたいですね。上記issueによればWebViewのバグらしく、[門](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7014)[票](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6079)を見る限り、長い間クローズされている気配はありません。ただ、こうすれば再生できるよというのもissueに書いてあって、`var m = new Media('/mnt/sdcard/download/notify.ogg', onSuccess, onError);
m.play();`を使えばいいそうです。
APIの詳細はhttps://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/doc/index.mdにあります。
ずれていたことを申し上げていたらすみません。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。